# Find the limit with L'Hopital's rule $\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin x\right)^{1/x} $

Tags: calculus, limits

I was solving this problem and wolfram alpha said it was $0$.But i just can't get it to $0$ using L'Hospital. 
Can you please show me how to do it.
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin x\right)^{1/x} $$

Comment: L'Hospital is not needed (and does not apply): $(0^+)^{+\infty}=e^{-\infty}=0$ is not an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $0\lt x\le \frac{1}{2}$, then $\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin x\le \frac{1}{3}$, since $\sin(\pi/6)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Thus for $0\lt x\le \frac{1}{2}$ we have
$$0\lt \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin x\right)^{1/x}\le \frac{1}{3^{1/x}}.$$
As $x\to 0^+$, $\frac{1}{3^{1/x}}\to 0$, so by Squeezing our limit is $0$.

**Remark:** L'Hospital's Rule is not the right tool: we are not dealing with an indeterminate form.

Comment: I'll just add for the OP that $\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin(x) \leq \frac{1}{3}$ $\forall x \leq \frac{1}{2}$ since arcsin(x) is an increasing function, and since $\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}) = \frac{1}{2}$